# Issue connecting to Heroku PostgreSQL from local GlassFish

Tags: java, postgresql, heroku, glassfish, heroku-postgres

I am trying to get a JDBC connection pool and resource setup in a local GlassFish server to connect to a Heroku PostgreSQL instance.

I have tried it in Tomcat setup as a resource and it works ok, but in GlassFish I have had some issues.

First up I had to downgrade my version of Java 8 to 151 to stop one error I was getting. Now when I try and execute the query in my app I get:

`java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)`

I think this is related to connections to Heroku PostgreSQL having to use SSL, but I am not sure what I need to do in GlassFish to configure that.

Does anyone have any experience doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of head scratching and Googling, I finally got this working. The exception above is a red herring. It is complaining it cannot connect to a local Derby database which is the GlassFish default resource. This means the problem was actually related to not being able to find the resource I specified.

Here are the steps I needed to get the connection working in GlassFish 5:

- Set JAVA_HOME to be JDK 1.8.0_151 (any newer version of 1.8 does not work) GlassFish needs to run on this version.
- In your Bean class use `@Resource(mappedName = "jdbc/postgresql")`. This was the only way I could get it to find my jdbc/postgresql resource (`@Resource(name = "jdbc/postgresql")`, `@Resource(name = "java:comp/env/jdbc/postgresql")` and `@Resource(lookup = "java:comp/env/jdbc/postgresql")` did not work).
- The connection Url must be like this:`jdbc:postgresql://<host>:<port>/<databse>?sslmode=require` (originally i had this `jdbc:postgresql://<host>:<port>/<databse>?ssl=true&amp;sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory` which had been working for me in other places).

So the key points are to use **JDK 1.8.0_151**, **mappedName** in the resource attribute and **sslmode=require** in the connection string.

Life should not be this complicated...

Comment: The difference between `sslmode=require` and `ssl=true&amp;sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory` has to do with postgresql JDBC driver version. The newer versions use `sslmode`.